# drill down report in IBM Cognos

Tags: cognos

Can we develop drill down reports in IBM Cognos other than by DMR(Dimensional Modeled Relation) technique? My reports are running slow when I drill down to lower level using a DRM package while my reports runs fine when I run the report directly on the lower level using a non-DRM package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a cube source such as Transformer or TM1, no.

If that option is unavailable to you - are you running your reports against a large fact table? If so, consider creating these reports against summary/aggregate SQL tables which contain a minimum of data.

Comment: I too figured out that for myself. Thank you though for the answer.